# Python subprocess with crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, subprocess

I am trying to run test.py every minute using crontab, which calls (after some other functions) test2.py with a parameter.
When I run "python3 test.py" in terminal, I see test2.py in the task manager. When I use the crontab, this isn't the case. Test.py does run, as I see output in the terminal. All files are in /root/.

Crontab:

```
PATH=/root
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/5.lockfile /usr/bin/python3 /root/test.py > /dev/pts/3
```

Test.py:

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

print(os.environ['PATH']) #Gives \root

#Three different methods, doesn't work:
subprocess.call("python3 /root/test2.py 1", shell=True) 
subprocess.Popen("python3 test2.py 1", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
os.system("test2.py 1")

time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: maybe python3 isn't in the path for the user that runs crontab. Anyway, you could consider not using shell=True and a string command line. Use `sys.executable` to find the current interpreter and make an argument _list_: `subprocess.call([sys.executable,"/root/test2.py","1"])`

Comment: Tthe path is usually different when running in Crontab. I would therefore try subprocess.Popen("python3 /root/test2.py 1") to make sure there is no confusion on locating test2.py.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, this worked. Please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that python3 isn't in the path for the user that runs crontab. So you have to make your script more foolproof.

You could consider not using `shell=True` and a string command line: it's bad practice and leads to issues (for instance with quoting, and also security issues)

Something that will work whatever the system path would be to use `sys.executable` to find the current interpreter and make an argument *list* to avoid future issues for instance with arguments containing special characters:

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable,"/root/test2.py","1"])
```

`sys.executable` is the full path to the interpreter which is currently running the script, so it's guaranteed to be found. The rest of the arguments don't depend on the user (except for permissions)

Also, maybe check return code of `subprocess.call` or, if the call *has to* be successful, replace by `subprocess.check_call`.

Another way would be to import `test2` and call one if its functions. That doesn't create another process, but that probably doesn't matter, and it has advantages (for instance: allowing to return python types, not breaking exception chain…)